# Read page source before POST

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-scripting

I want to know if there is a way to POST parameters after reading the page source. Ex: read captcha before posting ID#

My current code:

```
import requests
id_number = "1"
url = "http://www.submitmyforum.com/page.php"
data = dict(id = id_number, name = 'Alex')
post = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

There is a captcha that is changeable after every request to http://submitforum.com/page.php (obv not a real site) I would like to read that parameter and submit it to the "data" variable.

Comment: Are you wondering how to get a data from a webpage before loading this webpage ? _I feel like i'm missing a good schrodinger cat joke .._

Comment: You can use a get request, parse the page source, get the captcha ID/treat it, then send your post request using correct captcha data. But it will not always work depending on the captcha system in use. I finally ended using webbrowser emulation (ex: selenium python implementation) for this kind of purpose as it can be used to keep same session and such stuff. (Was doing captcha security analysis and auto completion of them)

Comment: @Arount I am trying to read the web page source so that I could grab a changeable value and add it to my data variable.

Comment: @Retsim Could you elaborate more on this? Wouldn't the get request give a different captcha than the post request? I assume I'll be doing 2 requests in this scenario?

Comment: @JeremyClaus Yes, you'll be doing 2 requests in this scenario, I can't see any other way (even emulating a browser, you will need two) - I still may be wrong -, as before sending anything, you need to parse the web page first. It's not always a problem as some captcha systems will not change their challenge (IP-based, time-based, session-based) and will allow you to adapt to this. If your captcha is different (ex: Google reCaptcha), webbrowser emulation is then the easiest way I know to achieve this without much efforts.

Comment: @Retsim Alright thanks mate. The problem here is not solving the captcha, but adding the captcha to the data variable. Care to provide a documentation to the method you mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: @JeremyClaus I added a code sample with some comments as a potential answer, from my selenium captcha analysis script using Selenium, hope it helps !

Comment: The point of captcha is to prevent bots and scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in OP comments, selenium can be used, methods without browser emulation may also exists !

Using Selenium (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of requests module method:

```
import re
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

regexCaptcha = "k=.*&co="
url = "http://submitforum.com/page.php"

# Get to the URL
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

# Example for getting page elements (using css seletors)
# In this example, I'm getting the google recaptcha ID if present on the current page
try:
    element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[src*="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k"]')
    captchaID = re.findall(regexCaptcha, element.get_attribute("src"))[0].replace("k=", "").replace("&co=", "")
    captchaFound = True
    print "Captcha found !", captchaID
except Exception, ex:
    print "No captcha found !"
    captchaFound = False

# Treat captcha
# --> Your treatment code

# Enter Captcha Response on page
captchResponse = browser.find_element_by_id('captcha-response')
captchResponse.send_keys(captcha_answer)

# Validate the form
validateButton = browser.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
validateButton.click()

# --> Analysis of returned page if needed
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Glad it helps !